# Ler log.txt do Servidor Remoto no Servidor Local em Tempo Real

Tags: log

Esses dias passou a ideia (devo ter lido em algum lugar e refrescou) de ter um programa no servidor local que está sincronizado com o servidor remoto, onde neste programa posso ver em tempo real o arquivo de logs do servidor, assim facilitando e dando mais rapidez na hora de consertar algum erro (que supostamente eu solicitei que fosse gravado ali).

Tem como? Em caso positivo, qual(is) seria(m)?

Comment: Tem. Sua dúvida está respondida :)

Comment: putz, rsrs. esqueci de perguntar qual :(

Comment: Qual o S.O. o servidor do cliente utiliza?

Comment: Local é Windows 7, o remoto é Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu sei que em Windows quando preciso de algo do tipo uso o **[Plink](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter7.html)**, utilitário do **[Putty](http://www.putty.org/)** que via SSH roda comandos em um servidor remoto trazendo a saída do comando remoto para o Windows.

Algo assim, por exemplo:

```
plink DEBIAN_SSH cat /var/log/messages
```

O Plink é um utilitário SSH portanto ele nada mais faz do que rodar um comando no servidor remoto e traz a sua saída como retorno, tudo usando SSH.

Logo, se o servidor local também é Linux, você pode usar o SSH direto:

```
ssh [USER-NAME]@[REMOTE-HOST] cat /var/log/messages
```

- Obviamente que este comando só pode ser executado como ROOT ou caso o usuário que loga tenha permissão no [**VISUDO**](http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/etc/sudoers-cabelo/) por exemplo.
- Vale lembrar ainda que você precisa ter uma chave de acesso no servidor local que permita conexão remota sem precisar de senha no servidor remoto, caso contrário, o comando irá exigir senha. Veja este **[link](http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Conexoes-SSH-sem-senha-facil-e-descomplicado)** se precisar criar uma par de chaves para acesso.

Mas acredito que o caminho seja esse.

Caso queira acompanhar a saída de log em tempo real o comando correto é o:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages
```

Referências nos links e também no link abaixo.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-running-commands-on-a-remote-host.html

Comment: Vou escolher sua resposta pois é a mais simples de se fazer, além de ser compatível com a maneira que quero proceder(windows -> linux). 
multitail parece ser uma boa por causa da display ser mais funcional e colorida, mas  precisa do cygwin64 para emular um comportamento de unix-like ou linux dist para rodar o multitail(pelo menos é o que deu a entender..)

Comment: Também acho bastante simples de usar o putty e seus utilitários, uso para diversas tarefas e esta que você precisou é só uma delas. É uma. Excelente ferramenta para ter sempre à mão!

Answer (score 3):

Use o programa `multitail`. Com ele você pode ver dois (ou mais) logs ao mesmo tempo, renderizados na linha de comando na mesma janela ou em janelas separadas.

Site oficial: http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/

**Alguns exemplos:**

Para ver dois logs locais ao mesmo tempo:

```
multitail /var/log/apache2/error.log /var/log/apache2/error.log.1
```

Para ver dois logs locais ao mesmo tempo, cada um em uma cor:

```
multitail -ci green /var/log/yum.log -ci yellow -I /var/log/mysqld.log
```

Para ver dois logs locais em duas colunas:

```
multitail -s 2 /var/log/mysqld.log /var/log/xferlog
```

Para ver dois logs remotos, cada um em uma máquina, ao mesmo tempo:

```
multitail -l 'ssh root@127.0.0.1 "tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log"' -l 'ssh root@127.0.0.2 "tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log"'
```

Answer (score 2):

Se ambos os servidores usam *Linux* como SO, uma boa opção é usar SSHFS. Esta permite ter uma pasta remota montada como partição no sistema local e não precisa da qualquer configuração complicada - basta só ter acesso por SSH ao servidor remoto.

Para montar uma pasta com logs do servidor remoto basta fazer:

```
sshfs utilizador@sistema_remoto:/var/logs/nginx/ /opt/remote_logs
```

Depois disso vai conseguir ler os logs remotos a partir da pasta `/opt/remote_logs` habitualmente.

Sistemas tais como Ubuntu ou Debian tem o pacote `sshfs` já nos seus repositórios.